# Capture and log the response body

Tags: java, servlets

I have a servlet that handle certain HTTP requests and responses. I want to log the response body before sending back to the client. Is there any way that I can capture the response body before it is send as a `HttpServletResponse` object from the servlet?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to log the response **body**?

As @duffymo pointed out, a `Filter` is indeed a suitable place for this. You can capture the response body by replacing the passed-in `ServletResponse` with a [`HttpServletResponseWrapper`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/10/apidocs/jakarta/servlet/http/httpservletrequestwrapper) implementation which basically replaces the `HttpServletResponse#getWriter()/getOutputStream()` with an own implementation which copies the response body into some buffer. After continuing the filter chain with the replaced response, just capture and log the copy.

You can find in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8933054/how-to-read-and-copy-the-http-servlet-response-output-stream-content-for-logging/8972088#8972088) a kickoff example how the `doFilter()` method can look like.

Comment: You should override not just `getWriter()`, but also `getOutputStream()`

Comment: @pihentagy: 1) If you need to. 2) Use the same which is set by `setCharacterEncoding()` method.

Comment: @BalusC: 1) how can you know which one is called by other `Filter`s or by the code, which processes the request?

Comment: AFAIK overriding `void write(int c)` is sufficient.

Comment: PrintWriter possibly also uses the OutputStream, so supporting a custom ServletOutputStream should be enough (which only needs a write(int) override).

Comment: @BalusC When you instantiate the `CopyPrintWriter` you already consume the response output stream by calling `getWriter` and as a result the wrapper object is not consistent anymore, leading to an `IllegalStateException`.

Comment: @Chishi: read the paragraph below the code snippet. It's just a kickoff example to give you the idea.

Comment: It gives me the idea, but the code you posted does not compile! At the moment I can't figure out how can I call **getWriter** without leading to an IllegalStateException like @Chishi pointed

Comment: @thermz: your comment is confusing. I don't see any compilation errors in the code. Aren't you mixing runtime exceptions with compilation errors?

Comment: you are right, I'm abolutely wrong! I used the wrong word, the code compile, but does not run for the reason explained before

Comment: I'd really like to know how to solve the runtime exception being thrown.

Comment: Solved, check https://gist.github.com/4400492 for working example. The problem, for me, was extending PrintWriter instead of ServletOutputStream.

Comment: Causes problem in my case, the `CopyPrintWriter` makes the jsp pages that allow user send Arabic letters to send as HTML entities.

Comment: @Muhammad: set response character encoding before getting writer.

Comment: Perfect!, I tried to set the response character encoding `after` the `getWriter` but didn't work. but After your advice, it is perfectly working.

Comment: @BalusC, I still need to know why it was working in the past without setting the char encoding, but after introducing your `CopyPrintWriter` it won't work unless I set the char enc?

Comment: @Muhammad: JSP will set it if `@page pageEncoding` is specified. However, this filter already gets the writer before JSP has the chance to set it, it's too late then to set the encoding.

Comment: @lm2s When using servlet API 3.1 or later, one gets a compile time error, because you didn't override two methods `isReady` and `setWriteListener`

Comment: spring boot 1.5.6 have got a runtime error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: getWriter() has already been called for this response

Comment: @[Im2s] looks like gist.github.com/4400492 this gist no longer exists.

Answer (score 19):

An alternative to [BalusC answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3242482/1203628)
Using the TeeOutputStream to write into two outputstreams at time.

```
public void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    final PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(baos);

    chain.doFilter(req,new HttpServletResponseWrapper(res) {
         @Override
         public ServletOutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException {
            return new DelegatingServletOutputStream(new TeeOutputStream(super.getOutputStream(), ps)
            );
         }
         @Override
         public  PrintWriter getWriter() throws IOException {
            return new PrintWriter(new DelegatingServletOutputStream (new TeeOutputStream(super.getOutputStream(), ps))
            );
         }
      });

    //Get Response body calling baos.toString();
}
```

Comment: For the benefit of future generations... which libraries are `TeeOutputStream` and `DelegatingServletOutputStream` from?

Comment: It's from spring and apache io. 1) https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/mock/web/DelegatingServletOutputStream.html 2)https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/io/output/TeeOutputStream.html

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Every solution I found was either long and drawn out or was specifically for calling getWriter... this allows the reading of the response body and having the application return that response to the user as well.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe a [servlet filter](http://java.sun.com/products/servlet/Filters.html) can help you.  Think of it as aspect-oriented programming for HTTP.

Comment: Funny how every other answer cites mine, but it wasn't the accepted one....

Comment: It was a helpful hint really (upvoted), but misses the hint about copying the `PrintWriter`