# How to redirect a Java ResponseWriter?

Tags: java, ajax, jsf, servlets

For debug reasons, I want to see the ouput of my ResponseWriter directly in standard output. Because the response will be processed by JavaScript I am not able to see the output there.

Is there an easy solution to redirect the ResponseWriter to standard output?

Comment: The accepted answer indicates that you're using JSF. You should really have mentioned that in your question and tags. This facility is namely not (directly) available in Servlet API.

Comment: I was not really aware that the ResponseWriter is only available in JSF, I added the tag

Comment: The package name of `ResponseWriter` tells that. Since you tagged `servlets` I initially thought that there's was some layman's ambiguity and that you *actually* meant `response.getWriter()` as you can obtain from `HttpServletResponse`. For that a completely different approach is needed, as suggested by Bozho and answered in detail by me [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3242236/capture-and-log-the-response-body).

Comment: The tag "servlets" was not added by me

Comment: Talking about ambiguity in `ResponseWriter` :) In future try to tag as specific as possible. Know what you're actually using. Look at package names and so on. It's not "just" Java and Ajax. Actually, Ajax has not much to do with the *actual* question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
ResponseWriter rw1, rw2; // ...
rw2 = rw1.cloneWithWriter(new PrintWriter(System.out));
```

Documentation for ResponseWriter

- http://developers.sun.com/docs/jscreator/apis/jsf/javax/faces/context/ResponseWriter.html#cloneWithWriter(java.io.Writer)

Use whichever writer your find most convenient

- http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17476_01/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html

And finally, system.out.

- http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17476_01/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#out

Comment: Thank you very much, works perfectly! Now I can go on finding my bug ;)

Answer (score 1):

There is - you can wrap your response and writer objects. But in this case there is a better solution: use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/). It will tell you what the response has been.