# How to get header from response in Servlet 2.3 or 2.5

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, servlet-filters, servlet-2.5

I know that v3.0 has method `getHeader()` but what about 2.3? Maybe it possible to get from steam?

UPDATE:

Actually, I need the HTTP response header RESTful application. In some reason I have decided to do this in servlet filter... but without success... 
Solution `@javax.ws.rs.core.Context HttpHeaders requestHeaders`.

For example,

```
@javax.ws.rs.GET
public String invoceRestMethod(@Context HttpHeaders requestHeaders){
      MultivaluedMap<String, String> map = headers.getRequestHeaders();
      for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
      //  processing header.... 
      }     
}
```

Maybe in will help for someone. But any case, for Servlet issue still is opened

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot get the header from the stream<sup>*</sup>.

What you have to do is insert a proxy response object into the filter chain before your Servlet is called, and have that capture the header.

---

<sup>* Actually, you could potentially capture stuff from the stream using a proxy response and decode the headers.  But if you are inserting a proxy response, it is simpler to capture the headers directly.</sup>

Comment: I guess you talk about HttpServletResponseWrapper(HttpServletResponse) . Yeap, I think about. But how I can know the length of header?

Comment: You don't need to know that.  You subclass the wrapper, overriding the `setHeader` method to record the headers that you are interested in.

Comment: Hi Stephen. I have tried to impalement this. It's work only in case if I invoke method setHeader in Servlet myself. But I need full HTTP header. Have you any idea?

Comment: Look at example #3 on this page: http://www.di.unipi.it/~ghelli/didattica/bdldoc/A97329_03/web.902/a95878/filters.htm.  And the examples linked to this Answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7046900/139985

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have done the same as you suggested http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3415004/log-only-http-servlet-response-headers . 
but it works only if I set header myself - in servlet class invoke response.setHeader(name, value). this value will be added but not full Header. 
On case of example #3 - it allow to get only body. 
Looks it's not possible to get header for servlet 2.5 :(

Comment: That should work in 2.5 provided that you add the filter far enough up the filter chain.  I'm not sure what you mean by "I need full HTTP header".