# HttpResponse headers in Servlet or Filter or Listener

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee, servlet-filters

How do we get http response headers like Content-Type, Server etc in HttpServletResponse? Need to get all the available such headers.

When we use openConnection of UrlConnection and use getHeaderFields, we get all such headers. But when we use getHeaderNames with HttpServletResponse, we are not getting such headers.

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
{

    Enumeration<String> requestHeaders = request.getHeaderNames();
    while(requestHeaders.hasMoreElements())
    {

        String header = requestHeaders.nextElement();
        System.out.println("request headerrrrrrr>>" + header);
    }

    Collection<String> responseHeaders = response.getHeaderNames();
    Iterator<String> it = responseHeaders.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext()){
        String header = it.next();
        System.out.println("response headerrrrrr>>" + header);
    }

    response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
}
```

In the chrome developer tool, I could see the below

```
General

Request URL:http://localhost:8080/TestWebApp/MyTestServlet
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Remote Address:[::1]:8080

Response Headers

Content-Length:22
Date:Fri, 03 Mar 2017 07:40:56 GMT
Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1

Request Headers

Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch, br
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:JSESSIONID=DF62FC092F67FBB02AF68BC646085065; ai_user=MKfG+|2017-03-02T10:44:54.721Z; _ga=GA1.1.1362801303.1488451499
Host:localhost:8080
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:1
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36
```

But console output is only request headers

```
request headerrrrrrr>>host
request headerrrrrrr>>connection
request headerrrrrrr>>upgrade-insecure-requests
request headerrrrrrr>>user-agent
request headerrrrrrr>>accept
request headerrrrrrr>>accept-encoding
request headerrrrrrr>>accept-language
request headerrrrrrr>>cookie
```

I did as mentioned in BalusC answer mention at [Log only http servlet response headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3415004/log-only-http-servlet-response-headers) . But seems to be not working as what I need

Created a filter with doFilter method as below

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, final ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

    DOMConfigurator.configure("C:\\log4j.xml");

    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(TestFilter.class);
    logger.info("do Filter TestFilter");
    final Map<String, List<String>> headers = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

    chain.doFilter(request, new HttpServletResponseWrapper((HttpServletResponse) response) {
        @Override public void setHeader(String name, String value) {
            List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
            values.add(value);
            headers.put(name, values);
            super.setHeader(name, value);
        }

        @Override public void addHeader(String name, String value) {
            List<String> values = headers.get(name);
            if (values == null) {
            values = new ArrayList<String>(); 
            headers.put(name, values);
            }
            values.add(value);
            super.addHeader(name, value);
        }
    });

    logger.info("headers size>>"+headers.size());
    logger.info("these are the headers>>"+headers);

}
```

And console log is

```
INFO    2017-03-03 05:14:23,765 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] com.test.TestFilter  - do Filter TestFilter
INFO    2017-03-03 05:14:23,768 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] com.test.TestFilter  - headers size>>0
INFO    2017-03-03 05:14:23,768 [http-bio-8080-exec-3] com.test.TestFilter  - these are the headers>>{}
```

Maybe I did miss something?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? A response is used to write stuff to the browser. So you should use it to *set* headers. Not to read them.

Comment: When we invoke servlets, we are getting response and response headers. And this response headers are getting printed in browser. So, same response headers, can we get it in the servlet or filter? Like the way We do get those headers as part of UrlConnection.getHeaderFields

Answer (score 0):

As it was said in comments, the servlet is responsible for generate the headers in the response to each http request.

Headers basically are used to create a conversation between client and server.

---

**GET Example**

**client**: Give me the `/ MyTestServlet` object, which I expect is an html page. If it's compressed it's better, but if not it's fine too.

```
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
```

**server**: Ok, I'm sending a html in charset iso-8859-1, sorry it's not zipped as you requested, is 9639 bytes long and it's last modification was on 13 Feb. BTW, I'm "MySuperServer".

```
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 9639
Last-Modified: Mon, 13 Feb 2017 12:47:56 GMT
Server: MySuperServer
```

The code of this GET would be:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    String contentType = request.getHeader("Accept");
    if (contentType.contains("text/html") || contentType.contains("*/*")) {
        // the client expects for a web page (or anything), so let's send it
        String page = createSomehowPage();
        response.addHeader("Content-Type", "text/html");
        response.addHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(page.length()));
        response.addHeader("Last-Modified", "Mon, 13 Feb 2017 14:42:56 GMT");
        response.addHeader("Server", "MySuperServer");
        response.getWriter().append(page);
        response.setStatus(200);
    } else {
        response.addHeader("Server", "MySuperServer");
        response.getWriter().append("Sorry, I don't serve the content-Type '").append(contentType).append("' you asked");
        response.setStatus(406); // 406=Not Acceptable
    }
}
```

You can find more information in [HTTP Headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers).

---

**EDIT**

There are headers that Tomcat sets automatically:

- `Server`: Mandatory header (see [Protocol's Server header definition](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.38)) that Tomcat Coyote sets using the [server.xml configuration](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html#Standard_Implementation) (see "server" part).
- `Date`: (see [Protocol's Date header definition](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.18))
- `Content-Length`: (see this [discussion about it](http://grokbase.com/t/tomcat/users/0319knkzrd/content-length-header-set-automatically))

In order to log all headers from Tomcat, you should consider [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34094030/log-all-http-requests-of-tomcat-server#answer-34096888), that basically says:

> Put an AccessLogValve in the Host or Context element e.g.:
>
> ```
> <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve"
>  directory="logs" prefix="mysitelog." suffix=".txt" 
>  pattern="..." resolveHosts="false" />
> ```

Comment: In my doGet, I haven't given any response.addHeader. But in Dev Console of browser, we still get 3 response headers. How do we capture those 3 headers. My requirement is to capture request and response headers for all http request hitting and put it into the log file. So I am trying to do that using a Filter. But in filter I am getting only request headers

Comment: I see, I altered my answer with a liitle more info.

Comment: I guess this will just write into a log file. I need to perform some processing before writing to log. Thats why I was trying to capture inside the code. Processing in the sense, modify the header name. Or send those captured values to another server. I also tried RequestDumperFilter, but that didnt capture those headers.