# JSP - write XML to console

Tags: xml, jsp

I have large JSP page, and there is XML creation on it.

For debug purpose i need to write that XML to console.

What is the easiest way to do this from JSP?

thank you very much on your time and energy, best regards

EXAMPLE:

...

My.jsp

```
...
    <portfolio>
      <stock>
        <symbol><c:out value="${bean.prop1}"/></symbol>
        <name><c:out value="${bean.prop2}"/></name>
        <price><c:out value="${bean.prop3}"/></price>
      </stock>
    </portfolio>
...
```

....

Now i want to print entire XML to console
to see if it is OK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this from the JSP on. Your best bet is to create a `Filter` which wraps the response using `HttpServletResponseWrapper` wherein you copy the response output. Finally log the captured response output. Long story short, here's a code example: [Capture and log the response body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3242236/capture-and-log-the-response-body).

If you want to log partial response, you've to parse the captured output yourself.

Answer (score 0):

It wouldn't be pretty, but you could use a StringBuffer in your JSP and build up your XML in the StringBuffer. Once it's built, issue the following commands:

```
<%
// write to log
System.out.print(buffer.toString);

// emit into JSP response
out.print(buffer.toString);
%>
```