# Servlets- How to read from a servlet output(out.println)

Tags: java, servlets

Could you please help me in reading a servlet output by using a java class/servlet.
Scenario : I have a servlet which prints "Hello World" say from out.println("Hello World).

I need to capture the output of that servlet in a java/servlet file and perform a task

Appreciate for any leads on this.

Thanks

Comment: Sample Snippet would be of more help. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

if out is the response stream then you can make call using [`HttpURLConnection`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) to read the output it prints on response.

**See Also**

- [how-to-use-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests *from BalusC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/how-to-use-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests)

Comment: Sample Snippet would be of more help.

Answer (score 0):

We can use [filters](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/filters-137243.html). And after "chaining" we can use response object to read the response string.

> chain.doFilter(request, response);

There is a similar question with full description. As it contains an extensive description, I am not repeating it here again.

- **REFER:- [Capture and log the response body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3242236/capture-and-log-the-response-body?answertab=oldest#tab-top)**

Comment: You forgot one important additional step. There is no standard way to read the body from `HttpServletResponse` directly. There's no `getInputStream()` method or something.