# Trouble determining which tomcat filter strips out data injected into httpservletresponse by our custom tomcat filter in filter chain

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, servlet-filters

Suppose you have the following filter chain:

Filter 1 ====> Filter 2 ====> Filter 3 ====> Our Custom Filter ====> Filter 4 ====> Filter 5

**<====Filter 1<====Filter 2**<==== Our Custom Filter <====Filter 3<====Filter 4 <==== Filter 5

We are injecting customized data structure ^

The problem is we don't see the injected data in the web browser when doing a "View Source".

So it is obvious to us that either filter 1 or 2 are removing the injected data.  In reality there are a lot more filters (possibly 30 or more).  We are trying to determine which filter is the culprit filter that removes our injected data.

Is there a way to write data to a HttpServletResponse that cannot be modified, and if a modification is attempted an exception is thrown in Java? This way it will reveal the culprit immediately.

Something like enabling zombies in Objective-C when you are trying to determine when code is trying to access an object that has already been released.

A few more details (in case you are interested):

The data structure we are injecting into the httpservletresponse is a JSON data structure surrounded by "script" tags because we use jQuery to parse it for a bunch of user-interface related things.

Interestingly enough, if we try to inject a random string like "hello stackoverflow" we can see this string when doing a "view source" in the web browser.  So our hunch is whatever filter is stripping out our structure is likely looking for malicious scripts and pulls our stuff out.

Comment: Is it possible to disable filters 8 and 9?

Answer (score 1):

Sure; you could write a read-only response wrapper and continue the filter chain with it.

[Trivial response wrapper example](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0400__Servlet/Filterthatusesaresponsewrappertoconvertalloutputtouppercase.htm) (It doesn't do what you want, it just shows how.)

I'm not convinced this is the *easiest* thing to do when you could just dump the response "in between" the existing filters without having to do any coding, just configuration.

Comment: Hi Dave - how would print "in between" existing filters? Where is this configuration?

Comment: @user1068636 Just insert a filter that examines it; should be doable.

Comment: Hi Dave - Do you know of an example somewhere online that explains how this can be done?  So far, the only thing I have tried is this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3242236/capture-and-log-the-response-body   however, this only logs the response when it is the current filter in the chain, not "in between" existing filters like you said above.

Comment: @user1068636 *Insert* a filter between the filters you want to know the behavior of.

Comment: Hi Dave - I inserted the PrintFilter in between each filter in "web.xml". Basically, every time I see two filter-mapping XML elements I would stick the PrintFilter in between.  I can see my print statements being called.  however, as soon as I login I get the following error "IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response"