# How to flush the response buffer through web.xml?

Tags: java, http, servlets

I have a typical scenario where I am sharing few filter classes in web applicaitons and client-server applictions.
In case of any exceptions in these filter classes, I have to send a particular json string to the clients. But nothing to the web applications (because I want to display a generic jsp).

I am using folloiwng code to send the response

```
 response.getWriter().println(responseObject.toString());
 response.flushbuffer();
```

Now the problem is that, my client application works fine but jsp displays the responseobj on top (because the reponse is committed).
But if I remove the flushbuffer(), then jsp works fine and I am not able parse the json object on client application.

I have no clue how to resolve this situation. I was wondering if there is a way to flush the response buffer through web.xml. So that I can change the client-server application's web.xml and leave the web application's web.xml as is.

Answer (score 0):

Once some HTML has left the server and is on its way to the browser, you cannot bring it back and change the response to JSON.

You have a couple of basic options I think:

- delay outputting the HTML (delay outputting anything really) until you are **sure** that is the correct/final response.
- use a response wrapper (like in this answer - [Capture and log the response body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3242236/capture-and-log-the-response-body)). I.e. buffer/save **all** of the response, and the filter can choose whether to use none of it, some of it, all of it, or return JSON instead.

Comment: Thanks Paul. I did not have to do any of this. I was able to receive the response at client without flushbuffer().