# How to intercept Spring MVC serialized response?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets, interceptor

I want to intercept Spring servlet response just at the end of the request. I mean, what i want to do is to log service response, that json which services returns and the statusCode. That is all what i want to log.

For that, i've already tried using HandlerInterceptorAdapter like this

```
public class ResponseLoggerInterceptor
    extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ResponseLoggerInterceptor.class);

    @Override
    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler,
        ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {
        LOGGER.info("Intercepted");
        super.postHandle(request, response, handler, modelAndView);
    }

}
```

That "handler" object is the object respose, but it is not serialized. Do you know where and how i have to intercept the very last servlet response? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will  need a 'HttpResponse' object
And will suggest that you do it in the 'afterCompletion' method

Comment: What do you mean by need a HattpResponse? Where does it appears? Thanks for your answer

Comment: Override the afterCompletion method

Comment: public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest request,
                            HttpServletResponse response,
                            Object handler,
                            Exception ex)
                     throws Exception

Comment: Are you trying to say that i have the response? Yes, i have it. Is the ResponseEntity object, and i know i have it, but that is not serialized yet. What i want is that object serialized (and i don't think that would be appropiate to serialize it by myself)

Comment: I assume you want to log the response?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what i want to do

Comment: Ok, good then override the afterCompletion method, and if you want to log a json response here is [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3242236/capture-and-log-the-response-body) for that