# Spring MVC - Get HttpServletResponse body

Tags: java, spring-mvc, servlets

Since after 2 days I still cannot figure how to perform a print of a `HttpServletResponse` body in `HandlerInterceptorAdapter`, I'll ask another time :)

With `HttpServletRequest` I can easily do something like `request.getReader().lines().collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator()));` and I have the full body but how to make the same with `HttpServletResponse`?

I Had found lots of question on StackOverflow about that but none of them seems to work.

This is the handler:

```
@Override
public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Exception ex)
        throws Exception {
    //how to print here the "response" by using the "response" parameter
    super.afterCompletion(request, response, handler, ex);
}
```

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30491790/how-to-intercept-spring-mvc-serialized-response) answer is quite the same and links to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3242236/capture-and-log-the-response-body) but they use `ServletResponse` and NOT `HttpServletResponse` and something with `FilterChain` which I have not in my `afterCompletion` handler. Even [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8933054/how-to-read-and-copy-the-http-servlet-response-output-stream-content-for-logging) that seems the most complete one is not suitable (I think) in my case.

Do someone can provide me a simple serialization example with `HttpServletResponse`?

Comment: Hi  Faraz Durrani thank you for the reply. I was looking for how to print body Response, not Request.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's been hard on searching deeply into it but found that `ResponseBodyAdvice` could be suitable for my purposes. So looking for some example on StackOverflow found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39963084/unable-to-intercept-and-manipulate-httpservletresponse-in-spring-boot/39963333#39963333) guy which had quite same issue having to manipulate the `Object body`.

That's my final working solution in order to implement what I wrote [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52118594/spring-mvc-add-custom-csrf-header-to-all-http-responses?noredirect=1#comment91188511_52118594)

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class CSRFHandler implements ResponseBodyAdvice<Object> {

    @Value("${security.csrf.enabled}")
    private String csrfEnabled;

    @Value("${security.csrf.headerName}")
    private String csrfHeaderName;

    @Value("${security.csrf.salt}")
    private String salt;

    @Override
    public boolean supports(MethodParameter returnType, Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> converterType) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Object beforeBodyWrite(Object body, MethodParameter returnType, MediaType selectedContentType,
            Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> selectedConverterType, ServerHttpRequest request,
            ServerHttpResponse response) {

        if (new Boolean(csrfEnabled).booleanValue()) {
            String csrfValue = SecureUtil.buildCsrfValue(salt, StringUtil.toJson(body));
            response.getHeaders().add(csrfHeaderName, csrfValue);
        }

        return body;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Simple answer is "you can't do that in a Handler Interceptor".
[Says so in the manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerInterceptor.html) :

> HandlerInterceptor is basically similar to a Servlet Filter, but in contrast to the latter it just allows custom pre-processing with the option of prohibiting the execution of the handler itself, and custom post-processing. **Filters are more powerful, for example they allow for exchanging the request and response objects** that are handed down the chain. Note that a filter gets configured in web.xml, a HandlerInterceptor in the application context.
>
> As a basic guideline, **fine-grained handler-related preprocessing tasks are candidates for HandlerInterceptor implementations, especially factored-out common handler code and authorization checks. On the other hand, a Filter is well-suited for request content and view content handling**, like multipart forms and GZIP compression. This typically shows when one needs to map the filter to certain content types (e.g. images), or to all requests.

So I advise you check out filter based solutions, as you pointed. You might be interested in : [ContentCachingResponseWrapper Produces Empty Response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39935190/contentcachingresponsewrapper-produces-empty-response) which seems to accomplish what you want with minimal coding. But once you get started with filters, any of the well accepted answers that you have linked to in the question will likely do the job.

Comment: Hi GPI thank you for you useful answer. It's clear why that's not a good way but trying OncePerRequestFilter or Filter it seems that doFilterInternal  or doFilter are not called after the controller execution. What should I use instead?

Comment: I'd guess that if your filter's method are not called, that is probably because Spring has not picked them up and deployed them. So you should probably read up the manual to see "how to register filters". The  way of doing it is different if you use a pure SpringBoot app, vs. a Servlet webapp embedding a Spring context, ... So read up the relevant documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with the following in Kotlin:

```
@Bean
open fun logFilter(): CommonsRequestLoggingFilter {
    val filter = InfoRequestLoggingFilter()
    filter.setIncludeQueryString(true)
    filter.setIncludePayload(true)
    filter.setMaxPayloadLength(10000)
    filter.isIncludeHeaders = false
    return filter
}
```

```
import org.apache.commons.io.output.TeeOutputStream
import org.springframework.mock.web.DelegatingServletOutputStream
import org.springframework.web.filter.CommonsRequestLoggingFilter
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream
import java.io.IOException
import java.io.PrintStream
import java.io.PrintWriter
import javax.servlet.FilterChain
import javax.servlet.ServletOutputStream
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper

class InfoRequestLoggingFilter : CommonsRequestLoggingFilter() {

    override fun beforeRequest(request: HttpServletRequest, message: String) {
        logger.info(message)
    }

    override fun afterRequest(request: HttpServletRequest, message: String) {
        // logger.info(message) - NOP, since doFilterInternal is logging it instead
    }

    override fun doFilterInternal(request: HttpServletRequest, response: HttpServletResponse, filterChain: FilterChain) {

        val outputStream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
        val printStream = PrintStream(outputStream)

        filterChain.doFilter(request, object : HttpServletResponseWrapper(response) {
            @Throws(IOException::class)
            override fun getOutputStream(): ServletOutputStream {
                return DelegatingServletOutputStream(TeeOutputStream(super.getOutputStream(), printStream)
                )
            }

            @Throws(IOException::class)
            override fun getWriter(): PrintWriter {
                return PrintWriter(DelegatingServletOutputStream(TeeOutputStream(super.getOutputStream(), printStream))
                )
            }
        })

        logger.info(String.format("%s ;status=%s ;payload=%s", createMessage(request, "", ""), response.status, outputStream.toString()))
    }
}
```