# Spring MVC - Add custom CSRF Header to all HTTP responses

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, csrf-protection

In my Spring MVC application, I want to implement a sort of CSRF header on annotated controllers methods.

I already have 100% working client's CSRF header parser implemented on the `HandlerInterceptorAdapter.preHandle` method and I used to try, in the same handler, the header generation for responses inside the on `afterCompletion` because that seemed to be the most suitable place for me:

```
@Override
public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Exception ex)
        throws Exception {
    if (handler instanceof HandlerMethod) {
        HandlerMethod handlerMethod = (HandlerMethod) handler;

        boolean requestCheck = handlerMethod.getMethodAnnotation(CSRF.class) != null;

        if (requestCheck && handlerMethod.getMethodAnnotation(CSRF.class).response()) {
            response.addHeader(payloadEncryptedHeaderName, SecureUtil.buildCsrfHeader(salt, response));
        }
    }

    super.afterCompletion(request, response, handler, ex);
}
```

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52113405/spring-mvc-get-httpservletresponse-body/52114075?noredirect=1#comment91183336_52114075) thread somebody told me that I could not use that method and using a Filter would have been the best but I noticed that in `doFilter`...

> 1. Cannot set headers to the response (or at least I could not find a way)
> 2. The method `doFilter` is invocated before the controller execution (and not after)

I really want to deeply understand how to deal with these interceptors so could someone explain me with an example the best place where I can manipulate the `HttpServletResponse` in order to accomplish my goal?

Comment: can this help? https://github.com/aditzel/spring-security-csrf-filter/blob/master/src/main/java/com/allanditzel/springframework/security/web/csrf/CsrfTokenResponseHeaderBindingFilter.java

Comment: Hi fantaghirocco thanks for the answer! Unfortunately the OncePerRequestFilter has the same behaviour of a Filter. I am seeking something that is triggered after the controller return in order to catch the return value and perform some operations on response headers.

Comment: 1. the same as in the interceptor. Everything before the call to `doFilter` is invoked before the controller, everything after the `doFilter` is invoked after the controller. Method calls passes through so you can do both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution on my other thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52113405/spring-mvc-get-httpservletresponse-body/52147866#52147866) it was all abount using `ResponseBodyAdvice` in order to achieve my goal.